# Unable to 'make' for Hello World, failed to fetch kernel headers

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-10.04

I am running a simple **hello world** program from 
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/hello2.html

But I am getting error
"make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.32-73-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2"

Earlier I was getting error "bounds.h not found" which found to be missing when I searched. Then I tried "make prepare" from the linux-headers-2.6.32-73-generic source directory. but failed. Then I did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

No success. Then I installed next release linux-headers-2.6.32-74, so I am having now 4 directories- linux-headers-2.6.32-73, linux-headers-2.6.32-73-generic, linux-headers-2.6.32-74 and linux-headers-2.6.32-74-generic.

Can anyone help me how to make it the new one as default library so that I can load my module "Hello world".

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/260176/lib-modules-2-6-38-8-generic-build-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Didn't work. I tried: **/usr/src$ sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-73/ /lib/modules/2.6.32-73-generic/build
ln: creating symbolic link `/lib/modules/2.6.32-73-generic/build': File exists**

Comment: Rebooted, didn't work. See, I have removed these 2.6.32-73 and 2.6.32-73-generic but kept backup. Is there any way to freshly install 2.6.32-73-generic and 2.6.32-73 linux headers? Also whenever I do **sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32-73** or "linux-headers-2.6.32-74", it says its already there.

Comment: Can you give an `ls` of your working directory?

Comment: $ ls 
**linux-headers-2.6.32-74  linux-headers-2.6.32-74-generic**

Comment: when doing **uname -r**, it gives **2.6.32-73-generic**. May be this will help.

Comment: @Olek, Alex,
I got it fixed:

On observing the changelogs of **linux-headers-2.6.32-73-generic** and  **linux-headers-2.6.32-74-generic**, there were no any changes in the **bounds.h** file in the later version. I just inserted my bounds.h file into the corresponding directory and it worked.

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R nice. Post the answer and mark it as correct - others may need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

On observing the changelogs of **linux-headers-2.6.32-73-generic** and **linux-headers-2.6.32-74-generic**, there were no any changes in the **bounds.h** file in the later version. I just inserted my bounds.h file into the corresponding directory and it worked.

All errors got removed and modules can be loaded successfully.